# Amazon s3 static web hosting caching

Tags: amazon-s3, web-hosting

I'm using Amazon S3 webhosting for my static html,js,css (etc..) files.
After replacing my index.html file, I still get the old version when consuming via the browser. 
I would like to set a default ttl **to the bucket** (and not to specific objects in it). I found this link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDefaultTTL

but can't find the "Object Caching" setting in the dashboard. can someone point out where it is?

Comment: The link you cited is for CloudFront, not S3.  If you are not using CloudFront, this information is not relevant.  If you are using CloudFront, this should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501465/how-to-add-cache-control-in-aws-s3

Answer (score 60):

Here's an [Amazon S3 link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3) that answers your question.  According to Amazon, you can't set the cache control header for the entire bucket unless you use a third party tool (that page links to a few).  One tool I ran across describes how to set the cache directives for objects submitted using a `PUT` request (or in bulk using their tool).  See [BucketExplorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-set-cache-control-header-for-s3-object.html) for more info.

Here is a cut-paste of Amazon's instructions (since S.O. doesn't like to rely on external links that might change or disappear):

**To add a Cache-Control or Expires header field to Amazon S3 objects using the Amazon S3 console**

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console
   at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3.
2. In the Amazon S3 console, in the buckets pane, click the name of the bucket that contains the files.
3. In the list of objects, select the first object to which you want to add a header field.
4. Click **Actions** and click **Properties**.
5. In the right pane, expand **Metadata**.
6. Click **Add More Metadata**.
7. In the **Key list**, click **Cache-Control** or **Expires**, as applicable.
8. In the **Value** field, enter the applicable value:
9. For a Cache-Control field, enter: `max-age=number of seconds that you want objects to stay in a CloudFront edge cache`
10. For an **Expires** field, enter a date and time in HTML format.
11. Click **Save**.

If you want to add a header field to additional objects, click the name of the next object, and repeat steps 5 through 9.

Comment: Notice that you can manage this behavior at a folder level too using the same procedure.

Comment: Something that added clarification for me when reviewing the Amazon S3 link. If you want Cloudfront to cache but not the browser, tl;dr make sure the s3 objects have max-age of zero but that Cloudfront has a minimum TTL set

Comment: this is working fine but when we are pushing new build and file getting replaced its removing cache headers is there any way it can auto set the headers of those files

Answer (score 12):

### **2022 AWS CLI V2 Method**

The simplest way to achieve this is to use [AWS CLI (S3)](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html). This can also be automated entirely for free using a tool like [GitHub actions](https://github.com/features/actions).

A static site should not have the `cache-control` set to a long-lived value on `HTML` files because the users will not see the updated version until the browser cache expires or manually busts their cache.

---

Due to AWS `CLI` restrictions, you have to do the following to set the cache for the whole bucket.

---

**Generic Example**

Upload the content and `--delete` old S3 content, and set `cache-control` on all content.

```
aws s3 sync [YOUR_LOCAL_SOURCE_CODE_PATH] s3://[BUCKET_NAME] --delete --cache-control max-age=31536000
```

Recursively remove `cache-control` headers from all `HTML` files and set the file back to type `HTML.`

```
aws s3 cp s3://[BUCKET_NAME] s3://[TO_BUCKET_NAME] --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.html" --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control max-age:no-cache --content-type text/html
```

---

**Notes**

- *TO_BUCKET_NAME is almost always the same as BUCKET_NAME*
- *If you modify an `HTML` file's metadata in AWS S3, you must also set the `content-type`, or it will automatically be set to a generic type causing the browser to download the file instead of rendering it in the browser.*

---

**Example**

```
// delete old files and upload files from the local directory to the s3 bucket, and set the cache-control header on every file.
aws s3 sync ./out s3://www.test.com --delete --cache-control max-age=31536000

// copy all files and remove cache control header from only HTML files and set back to html content type
aws s3 cp s3://www.test.com s3://www.test.com --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.html" --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control max-age:no-cache --content-type text/html

// bonus - if using CloudFront - small site can invalidate all cache (/*)
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=123ABCDEFG --paths "/*"
```

Comment: Hi Sean. Just a quick explanation about the edit I made that you then reverted. If you insist that you intend to comment on another answer, then you should _comment_ on that answer _when you have earned the privilege_. Don't use answers to respond to answers - this isn't a threaded discussion forum. I figured the information you had was helpful to the OP and others who may come along with the same problem, so it was worthwhile tweaking your post to _sound_ like an answer, and avoid getting deleted.

Answer (score 2):

If you use AWS CLI you can add `--cache-control` or `--metadata directive` per synced object

Here are my npm scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.config.prod.js",
    "sync": "aws s3 sync public/ s3://[BUCKET_NAME] --delete --cache-control max-age=31536000",
    "invalidate": "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id [DISTRIBUTION_ID] --paths \"/*\"",
    "deploy": "npm run prod && npm run sync && npm run invalidate"
  },
```

Answer (score -5):

Yes. In case you are using the CloudFront Distribution - you just need to check your invalidation and why your object invalidation didn't work properly. What is TTL value.

Do you use CDN?

Comment: Setting S3 Cache-Control is different to setting Cloudfront TTL which just controls how long your file stays in the Cloudfront cache. Nothing to do with Browser Caching.