# Latest html file uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket is not reflected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded a html file to an Amazon S3 bucket. What i observed is that it is not showing the latest html file, in this case it is showing previous file content.

Please suggest, i have checked the cache-control and other properties.

Comment: I know that --"Amazon S3 buckets in all Regions provide read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects and eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES."

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531643/amazon-s3-static-web-hosting-caching

Comment: Thanks Jarmod, but this won't help. I have already tried adding cache-control and expires paramters but no luck.